# What is D2007 doing with degree symbols on Japanese/Korean/Chinese OS

Tags: delphi, cjk, codepages

I have an app that uses ° (degree symbol , ANSI #176) in various places and I cannot understand the different ways it displays - some are correct but others look as if there's been a conversion to UTF-8 and then back to ANSI. Generally it appears OK in TLabels but not TEdits and occasionally OK in a TRichEdit. Recompiling in XE5 makes no appreciable difference. So my question is - how do I get #176 to appear consistently on western and eastern OS's.

Comment: `#176` is only the degree symbol in some code pages. This cannot possibly work on systems that use a different code page. You say it still doesn't work in XE5. It should. D2009 and higher, including XE5, use Unicode strings, which behave the same on all Windows versions. Can you post a simple example that shows the problem on XE5?

Comment: But it should work on systems on which #176 is the degree symbol in the current code-page and, as far as I can tell, (not being fluent in anything other than English) that this is the case on all the far Eastern OS's I've tried. Charmap.exe shows 0xB0 as "degree symbol" for all the character sets listed.

Comment: In Charmap, click "Advanced view", and you will see the character set is Unicode. To see some of the code pages' characters, choose a different character set in that dropdown list.

Comment: "..for all the character sets listed."  All - DOS and Windows, Arabic through to Traditional Chinese - show 0xB0 Degree symbol

Comment: No, they don't show 0xB0. In the character sets where the symbol exists at all, they show U+00B0 (the Unicode code point), but my point was that when it exists at all, the position in the screen varies (and that position is based on the code it has in that code page), and there are also code pages where it doesn't exist at all: try Windows: Thai, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But my point is that as Char(176) works how do I stop e.g. Chinese Windows from doing something funny with Char(176)+'C'? I presume that somewhere there is something that is being interpreted as a MBCS but if so what can I do to stop it?

Comment: What you can do to stop it is use Unicode strings. That's why in my first comment, I said it should work with XE5, and asked you for a concrete example of what doesn't work.

Comment: Don't guess, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964653) - click on each code page and see if #176 is ° or not (to be fair, it is - in all but one SBCS). You'll also quickly realize why it's not, in the DBCS pages.

Comment: maybe the font you are using has no representation por that symbol?

Answer (score 2):

Your entire approach is flawed. The character you are referring to, #176 is the degree symbol in some ANSI code pages, but not all. And in the far eastern locales, that use double byte character sets, #176 is meaningless on its own. Because it is part of a double byte character. If you wish your application to work well in all locales you will need to code it using Unicode text.

You claim that switching to XE5 does not help. Clearly you aren't doing it right. XE5 has full and comprehensive support for Unicode. If you use it correctly then it will solve your problem.

Comment: Not fatally flawed I hope and as my main aim is to get this working in D2007 I would like to get to the bottom of the behaviour. The curious thing is that code such as Label1.Caption := '°F ºF '+#176+'F '+#186+'F' produces garbage (not even Chinese characters according to my colleague) but StringGrid1.Cells[1,1] := Char(176); works as expected. This is in D2007 BTW.

Comment: @user3359525 Yes totally flawed. It isn't ever going to work in D2007 using ANSI. You have to remember that the code pages you are talking about are double byte code pages. You need to use Unicode.

Comment: @user3359525 I'm very surprised that you say it works as expected with a string grid in D2007. Is your string grid the standard Delphi TStringGrid, or are you using some custom third-party string grid?

Comment: Never say never. This code works as expected: StringGrid1.Cells[1,1] := Char(I); but this doesn't: StringGrid1.Cells[1,I-27] := Char(I)+'C'...

Comment: Never say never? You deny that some things are impossible? I guess I cannot help you any further in that case.